# Need to set Timeout on php function like fopen, file_get_contents and fread

Tags: php

Since the socket/stream wait time is not included in PHP max execution time.
For server performance improvement,
I require to set a timeout for fopen, file_get_contents and fread functions 
if they do not process within PHP execution time.
I have tried with below example
    **Program:**

```
    $fileName = 'C:/svn/trunk/storage/invoices/BAI_Export.txt';
    $fp       = fopen( $fileName, 'rb' );
    if( !$fp ) {
        echo "Unable to open\n";
    }else {
        stream_set_timeout( $fp, 2 );
        $res = fread( $fp, filesize( $fileName ) );
        $info = stream_get_meta_data( $fp );
        fclose( $fp );
        if( $info['timed_out'] ) {
            echo 'Connection timed out!';
        }else {
            var_dump( $info );
        }
    }
```

** OutPut:**

```
Array
(
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] => 
    [wrapper_type] => plainfile
    [stream_type] => STDIO
    [mode] => rb
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 1
    [uri] => C:/svn/trunk/storage/invoices/BAI_Export.txt
 )
```

Here in output, "time_out" parameter gets empty.
Please let me know if alternate solutions are there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could the following

```
set_time_limit(0); # If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.
```

Comment: I need complete all the execution within 60 sec and sometimes these PHP functions could take more time to send a response. I need to complete all its execution within 60 sec, otherwise, PHP function should give timeout error.

Comment: I know for 45 seconds you have set it to 20. I think for 60 seconds it 30.

Comment: I have set a timeout in stream_set_timeout function for 2 sec only. I have other PHP operations that are performed before calling this block of code.